# Select rows with the same count in a column from a table

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Person (Ssn, Name, Age, Petname)
```

I need to form a question that returns the name of all persons that have the same amount of pets as the person with Ssn = 1 (i.e. if the person with Ssn = 1 has Petname = "Zeus" in the Petname all the persons that also have a pet should be returned). I know the table design is stupid but it's from a school asignment and has to look like that.

This is what I've got so far. I think it's partly right but I can't seem to figure it out completely:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM   Person 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(Petname) FROM Person WHERE Ssn = '1')
       = (SELECT COUNT(Petname) FROM Person WHERE Ssn != '1');
```

Comment: Do your own homework. You'll learn more that way.

Comment: Sorry, Pnr is the swedish version of Ssn. Forgot to translate it. And about the do your own homework comment. I sat two hours straight trying to figure it out. I agree that you learn more from doing it on your own, but when you really can't figure it out you have to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Person
WHERE SSN <> 1
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(PetName) = (SELECT COUNT(PetName) FROM PERSON WHERE SSN='1')
```

Here is also a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64860/16) with the code.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. The having clause really made it a lot easier. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Name from Person 
group by Name 
having 
sum(case when Pnr = '1' then 1 else 0 end) = sum(case when Pnr <> '1' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one person has only one and only one pet.

```
SELECT 
    Name
FROM 
    Person 
WHERE 
    PetName = (SELECT Petname FROM Person WHERE Ssn = 1)
    AND Ssn <> 1
```

Comment: Why assume such a thing?